# Qt Creator - Add keyboard shortcuts to Menu entries

Tags: c++, qt, keyboard-shortcuts, qt-creator, qkeysequence

I created the shortcut events, such as:

```
new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_Q), this, SLOT(close()));
```

But now I would like to show "Ctrl+Q" in the menu entry here:

[image: Exit]

How do I do that? I don't seem to find a way to do that in Qt Creator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you would use `QAction` class for this, so you would have a `QMenu` to which you will add actions, in your case `CLOSE`. Then you can use `SetShortcut` to add `"CTRL + Q"` in menu.

```
pNewAction->setShortcut(QString(strAccel.c_str()));
```

where `pNewAction` is of type `QAction`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. So, you wouldn't use Qt Creator to create the menus (as it changes the XML instead of creating C++ code); you would create the menus yourself with QMenu and QAction, so that you are able to set up the shortcuts. Is that correct?

Comment: You can create menus in QtDesigner (or inside Qt Creator) if your window is a QMainWindow. You create the QAction instances and then drag-and-drop them into the menu.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the shortcut keys in the QtDesigner in the 'Action Editor' (Tab at the bottom, the 'Signal/Slot Editor' tab is selected by default).

Here all defined QActions are listed. A double click on a field in the 'shortcut' column will open the wanted dialog.

This will add the shortcut to the QAction (create triggered events) and set it as visibile text, e.g. in the menu entry (only visible in the application, not in QtDesigner).

In the 'Property Editor' are more options for the 'shortcuts' (e.g. make them translatable).

[image: Add shortcuts to QActions in the Action Editor]